# 18 rounds encryption in embedded?

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis, block-cipher

I have a power trace of a decryption.
It seems like I'm watching a 18 rounds decryption algorithm.
I cannot think about any other algorithm implemented in ASIC except Cammelia who has 18 rounds.

Which other algorithms are commonly used in ASIC and has 18 rounds ?

Also it seems it receive 128 bits block size.

Comment: Are you sure that aren't any rounds calculated twice to counter differential fault attacks?

Comment: @j.p. actually I don't know ... I would like to post here a power trace after filter and see what do you think

Answer (score 2):

The only 2 "common" algorithms that I know off the top of my head with 18 rounds are Clefia and Camellia with 128-bit keys.

Anubis may also be an option, I believe that with a 320-bit key it uses 18 rounds, I have no idea why that would be used instead of AES.

I suppose it is also trivial to add rounds to AES or Twofish in hardware, both the key schedule and round function support additional rounds without modification to their core.

Comment: Interesting ... About the AES I checked for a correlation with the sbox leakage model and could not find one.  I will check for the  Clefia - seems interesting